# Fixing changing characters a regular expression

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

I have a regular language $L$ from characters of $\Sigma_1$, we define: $\Sigma_2=\Sigma_1\cup \{+,-\}$ and
$$L^{+-}=\left\{a_1\cdot p\cdot a_2\cdot q \cdot a_3\cdot\ldots \cdot a_k\mid a_1,a_2\ldots,a_k\in L,p\in\{+,-\},q\in \{+,-\}\setminus\{p\}\right\}$$

I want to show this is still a regular language. To do so with an DFA is easy, so I would like to do so using only regular expressions and basic closure rules of regular languages.

But since the $+$ and $-$ need to alter, this is getting complicated. I try proving by induction on the length of the regular expression $r$ for $L$, but I find it hard to see how to do when $r=(r_1)^*$. For a concatenation of $r_1\cdot r_2$ I can manage. But how do I approach $*$ when the symbols $+$ and $-$ need to alter?

Comment: You can concatenate $L^+=L\cdot\{+\}$ and $L^-=L\cdot \{-\}$. Since $L$ is regular, so are $L^+$ and $L^-$. Next we can concatenate $L_2^+=L^+L^-$ and $L_2^-=L^-L^+$. Now we take Klene star $(L_2^+)^*$ and $(L_2^-)^*$. Finally we take their union $L^{+-}=(L_2^+)^*\cup(L_2^-)^*\cup L^+\cdot(L_2^-)^*\cup L^-\cdot (L_2^+)^*$. The first set in the union are the words with an even number of blocks of word from $L$ and sign and the first sign a plus. The second set in the union is the same but with the first sign a minus. The other two sets are the words with an odd number of blocks.

Comment: @plop I want a different language, where I push $+$ or $-$ between every two origonal characters.